# checkbox should remains checked after refresh the page refresh

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8, angular9

So here I'm using checkbox to hide and show templates. I just want code that will make checkbox remains checked after page refresh in angular 9 .Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things:

1. Use RxJS and as soon as the checkbox is checked, you can use Behavior Subject to store the data and on reload or refresh event, read the behavior subject and patch the value
2. Use sessionStorage, and do the same. As soon as its checked, store it in sessionStorage, on reload, try to read from sessionStorage and patch the value again.

Implementation:

```
// Using session storage

someForm.controls.checkboxFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('checkboxChecked', true)
    }
})

onRefreshEvent() {
 let sessionStorageValue = sessionStorage.setItem('checkboxChecked'); 
 if (sessionStorageValue && (sessionStorageValue === true)) {
    this.someForm.contols.checkBoxControl.patchValue(true)
 }
}


//// Same with Behavior Subject as well

// Create a Behavior Subject in your Service file
checkboxCheckedSource: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
checkBoxObservable: Observable<boolean> = this.checkboxCheckedSource.asObservable();

setCheckboxValue(checked: boolean) {
  this.checkboxCheckedSource.next(checked);
}

getCheckboxValue(): Observable<boolean> {
  return checkBoxObservable;
}

// In your component.ts file

someForm.controls.checkboxFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data) {
        this.yourService.setCheckboxValue(true)
    }
})

onRefreshEvent() {
  this.yourService.getCheckboxValue().subscribe(checked => {
    if (checked) {
       this.someForm.contols.checkBoxControl.patchValue(true);
    }
  })
}
```

If its only one checkbox, i would prefer the sessionStorage way of doing it, else if you are storing a lot of checkboxes use BehaviorSubject!!

Comment: Do you know how to find if the page (home page) is refreshed or not ? Note that this home page has no routing. So router events is not working. Thank you.